# Using dynamically filled combobox's new value in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I fill combobox dynamically with javascript;

```
var $select = $('#itemsize');
$select.empty();
$(data).each(function (index, o) {
$select.append('<option value="' + o.Size + '">' + o.Size + '</option>');});
```

That code is running perfectly and running another function after that (GetProductInfoWhereSize). 
I'm using this combobox's selected value in that function. 
Function like this;

```
function GetProductInfoWhereSize() {
var size = -$("#itemsize").val();
console.log(size);
}
```

But `GetProductInfoWhereSize` shows me old values.
How do I use new value in this function?

Sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the function in the onchange event of the select, try with this:

```
$( "#itemsize option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Hi @Jersono,
thanks for your answer but its not working :(